# What mathematicians were responsible for MV Calculus

Tags: calculus, math-history

I'm taking MV calculus now. We are doing double integrals, polar integrals, etc.

I'm curious to know what mathematicians are primarily responsible for developing these techniques. It would be easy to say Newton or Leibniz (and that may be right). But it seems like Riemann had a big role ("The Riemann sums.") How about Euler, Gauss, or countless others?

So who developed polar coordinate calculus? Double integrals? Did Newton and Leibniz use MV equations?

Thanks!

Comment: The history is somewhat muddled by the fact that a lot of math was developed with very limited rigor and then redeveloped with more rigor down the line, with most of the results still going through (in some cases with some more explicit assumptions to avoid pathologies that were discovered later). Names that persist to this day often only got attached to things during that second pass of making things more rigorous. As a concrete example, the notion of integral is older than Riemann.

Comment: For beotians like me, it took me some time to understand that MV = Multi-variable..., not Mean Value, not MiniVolt,...:)

Comment: Multi Variable Calculus begins around the 1750s with Euler and a lot of others. But for example, you could look in vain for curls, gradient, and div till the end of the 19th century due in particular to a giant physicist called Gibbs. The same for dot-product and cross-product.

Comment: It is is any solace, I had to look up "beotian." So we're even.

Comment: And thanks too for pointing me to Josiah Gibbs. I didn't know of him. He's a giant! Seems like he is forgotten ot history. But Einstein called him the greatest mind America has produced! Wow.

Comment: This is more suited for mathematics history stack @user27847